# Collectd Permission denied to Log File

Tags: logging, collectd

I have collectd running and I start it as root with:

```
service collectd start
```

However, I am not able to see the logs. I get the following when I run: service collectd status:

```
logfile plugin: fopen (/var/log/collectd/collectd.log) failed: Permission denied
logfile plugin: fopen (/var/log/collectd/collectd.log) failed: Permission denied
logfile plugin: fopen (/var/log/collectd/collectd.log) failed: Permission denied
logfile plugin: fopen (/var/log/collectd/collectd.log) failed: Permission denied
logfile plugin: fopen (/var/log/collectd/collectd.log) failed: Permission denied
```

The permissions on the file system are as follows:

```
[root@avocado]# ls -la /var/log/collectd/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root root 4096 Aug 16 06:07 .
drwxr-xr-x. 20 root root 4096 Aug 16 06:00 ..
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    0 Aug 16 06:07 collectd.log
```

I created the /var/log/collectd folder and /var/log/collectd/collectd.log file manually while trying t troubleshoot this problem.

The collectd configuration is as follows:

```
#LoadPlugin syslog
LoadPlugin "logfile"
#LoadPlugin log_logstash

<Plugin "logfile">
    LogLevel "info"
    File "/var/log/collectd/collectd.log"
    Timestamp true
    PrintSeverity false
</Plugin>
```

What am I missing? How can I get collectd to stop complaining about permissions and log properly?

Comment: Most likely it's SElinux. What does `getenforce` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's SElinux. What does getenforce return?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was selinux, and this fixed it:

```
setenforce 0
```

Comment: To make `setenforce 0` persistent over a reboot, edit `/etc/selinux/config`: `SELINUX=permissive`

Comment: What does this command do? Why will it help the OP? I think it would be best if you could [edit] your answer to include a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install policycoreutils-python
```

then

```
semanage permissive -a collectd_t
```